# Dynamically generating React elements not assignind properties

Tags: reactjs

I want to use my `ViewModel` Component to dynamically create elements and assign properties to them. The code I have is rendering, but not what I expect. It's rendering the text in a div instead of creating my custom `Debug` element.

Here is Debug:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Debug extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<h3>
      {this.props.o}
    </h3>)
  }
}

export default Debug;
```

I want `props.o` to be a shorthand for object assigned to an element, assigned in `ViewModel`:

Here is my `ViewModel`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ViewModel extends Component {
  loadData() {
    this.setState({});
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadData();
    if (!this.state) { return; }
    let stateKeys = Object.keys(this.state);
    console.log(stateKeys);
    if (stateKeys.length <= 0) { return; }
    let elems = {};
    console.log("My statekeys" + stateKeys);
    for (let key of stateKeys) {
      let stateValue = this.state[key];
      console.log("My state value: " + stateValue);
      let tagName = stateValue[0];
      let values = stateValue[1];
      elems[key] = values.map((item, i) => {
        return React.createElement(tagName, {o: item, key: key + "" + i});
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    let keys = Object.keys(this.state);
    let output = [];
    for (let k of keys) {
      let group = this.state[k];
      for (let elem of group) {
        output.push(elem);
      }
    }
    return (<div>{output}</div>)
  }
}
```

And using with:

```
class Fight extends ViewModel {
  loadData() {
    console.log("Loading data with recent");
    this.setState({
      recent: [Debug, ["Lightning Blast for 155, Critical!", "Enemy Fire Punches for 70."]]
    });
  }

export default ViewModel;
```

HTML output:

```
<div><div>Lightning Blast for 155, Critical!Enemy Fire Punches for 70.</div></div>
```

No h3. The CreateElement seems to be putting the text into the body when I want it to go into the props.

Comment: I think you'd want to do something like `<this.props.o />` since you're exporting the class, not the rendered JSX.

Comment: The Debug class is the tag I want to generate. I'm having difficulty dynamically generating a react element from a string

Comment: Yes, my comment still holds. Try it out

Comment: If that worked, see that you add an answer so that we can close out the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for dynamically generating tags in React:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Debug extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<h3>
      Hey{this.props['o']}
    </h3>)
  }
}

export default Debug;

class Fight extends ViewModel {
  loadData() {
    console.log("Loading data with recent");
    let myState = {
      "recent": [Debug, ["LBlast", "FPunch."]]
    };
    this.setState(myState);
  }
```

ViewModel

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ViewModel extends Component {
  loadData() {
    this.setState({});
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state) {
      return (<div></div>)
    }


    if (!this.state) { return; }
    let stateKeys = Object.keys(this.state);
    console.log(stateKeys);
    if (stateKeys.length <= 0) { return; }
    let elems = {};
    console.log("My statekeys" + stateKeys);

    for (let key of stateKeys) {
      let stateValue = this.state[key];
      console.log("My state value: " + stateValue);
      const TagName = stateValue[0];

      console.log("What is tagname?" + TagName);
      let values = stateValue[1];
      elems[key] = values.map((item, i) => {
        console.log("My item is" + item);
          return <TagName o={item} key={key + "" + i}/>;
      });
    }

    let keys = Object.keys(elems);
    let output = [];
    for (let k of keys) {
      let group = elems[k];
      for (let elem of group) {
        output.push(elem);
      }
    }
    console.log(output);
    return <div>{output}</div>
  }
}

export default ViewModel;
```